# Html.BeginForm wont call post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

I try to insert image to server, in view i use mvc2, my code is:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Main", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{%><br />
   <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" size="25" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />      
<% } %>
```

In MainController I use:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Images")
                        , Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
     }
```

But when i go on `submit` button nothing happen i try to debug and I see that `public ActionResult Upload` are not calling.
What can be problem?

Thanx

Comment: "Nothing happens" is a pretty vague description of the behavior.  If the browser isn't posting the form at all then that has nothing to do with your server-side code.  What is the resulting client-side HTML?  Is there any JavaScript intercepting the form post?  Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?  Is any request sent to the server at all?  What is the response for that request?  There is *a lot* of debugging you can do here.

Comment: I don't really get, if you write your code in VS it gives you an error that your method don't have a return value, you need stackoverflow for this? Or you don't have pasted all your method?

Comment: I'm tried this code and working good,but your code has one error
you are wrong path you select for your use HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Images") it should be HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would not compile, you need to return an `ActionResult` from within the action i.e.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Images")
                        , Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
        // Below line is missing
        return View();
     }
```